# How to stop auto refresh of my login page after session timeout in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session

I am trying to make an MVC app which must automatically timeout of a session after a certain period (Let's say 2 minutes). I have used this to set the session timeout in Web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2">
  </sessionState>
```

And this is the code to redirect if the session has timed out:

```js
<script>
            (function (delay) {
                

    function getTimeout() {
        return setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Make SESSION expire');
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'
        }, delay);
    };

    // start the session timer
    var timeoutSession = getTimeout();

    $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
        console.log('timeout reset');
        clearTimeout(timeoutSession);
        timeoutSession = getTimeout();
    });
    })(2*60*1000);
        </script>
```

All this works fine and the app Logs out after 2 mins of in activity perfectly.
However, the problem I face is that the Login page which I redirect to after auto signout keeps refreshing after 2 mins even after the session has timed out. Can you help me stop this refresh when there is no session running?

Edit:
Found the issue, I was using the script in the _layout file which caused every page to refresh. Now I used the code into the page just after login(Say page 1) and it has stopped refreshing.

But now, there's another issue, the app only auto-logs out from this page(page 1). If I go to some other page from page 1(say page 2), the app does not log out from page 2.

Comment: Simple, don't inject this code on the login page.

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888 , this solved the issue somewhat.